# Mediasoup Logic - Confusing Flow

Tags: mediasoup

I'm a bit stuck with the media-soup logic. Following https://jasonkang14.github.io/posts/webrtc/webrtc-Mediasoup-flow-explained and the examples.

Specially Step 5 "Consume"

It's not clear if we are supposed to create a new consumer for every new producer or the client has a one way consumer with the media-soup server that triggers with each new producer?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the official mediasoup documentation instead:

https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v3/

In addition, the support forum of mediasoup is here:

https://mediasoup.discourse.group/